# Visiting professor opportunities for PhD candidates

Tags: professorship, economics

In my field, economics, I occasionally see opportunities for ABD PhD Candidates to apply for one- or two-semester visiting professor positions (presumably as sabbatical cover). I have only ever heard of two such opportunities, and each was through an email forwarded by our graduate adviser. Are these positions advertised centrally anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.aeaweb.org/joe/listings.php

has a big centralized list of econ jobs (at all ranks) in the US. If you're not in the US you could try looking for such information at the website of the large professional organizations in your country.

Comment: I did not expect to see visiting positions on AEA, but you're correct that there are some there. Do you think they would appear there even if they are announced late (i.e. in the Spring)? Nice name, btw.

Comment: I'd imagine that'd be where most stuff is going to apply. Let's wait and see if an actual economist shows up who can confirm for us, but I'd guess that website is your best bet. Seems to have some non-US stuff too.